# How to calculate P(X1>X2) using naive bayes?

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, naive-bayes

Hello I'm struggling with how to calculate P(X1≥X2) using the table and the Naïve Bayes from this question [image]

Comment: Is this homework ? You should add tag `self-study` to your question.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our tour, which has information for new users. 
Please  tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Evaluate $X_1 \geq X_2$ into a new column. Consider it as a variable just like you would do with $X_1$ or $X_2$ and then calculate the resulting individual and conditional probabilities.

Comment: When you said 'Evaluate X1≥X2' like cases when X1=1, X2=0 and X1=1, X2=1 so the probability of that is 4/10 and 1/10 respectively but i have no idea how to use naive bayes for this

Comment: Would P( X1≥X2)= P(X2=0)P(X1=0|X2=0)+P(X2=1)P(X1=1|X2=0)+P(X2=1)P(X1=1|X2=1)+..... so on?

Comment: I would rather go the other way. Consider that $P(X_1 \geq X_2) = P(X_1 = 1 | X_2 = 0) + P(X_1 = 1 | X_2 = 1) + P(X_1 = 0 | X_2 = 0)$ and apply the bayesian formula.